# bash perl options for one expression, others for another, in the same command

Tags: bash, perl, delimiter

I have file1.txt

```
text1
text1
text1
text2
text2
text2
text1
text1
text1
```

and file2.txt

```
text1
text2
text2
text1
text1
text1
```

I have a command with pipe:

```bash
perl -pe 's/text2$/text4/' file1.txt file2.txt | perl -0pe 's/text1$/text3/'
```

That gives me the output:

```
text1
text1
text1
text4
text4
text4
text1
text1
text1    #EOF file1.txt
text1
text4
text4
text1
text1
text3    #EOF file2.txt
```

but I want:

```
text1
text1
text1
text4
text4
text4
text1
text1
text3    #EOF file1.txt
text1
text4
text4
text1
text1
text3    #EOF file2.txt
```

So I tried this command:

```bash
perl -pe 's/text2$/text4/; ' -0e 's/text1$/text3/' file1.txt file2.txt
```

Which unexpectedly applies the "null" record delimiter to both expressions and not just the last one, resulting in:

```
text1
text1
text1
text2
text2
text2
text1
text1
text3    #EOF file1.txt
text1
text2
text2
text1
text1
text3    #EOF file2.txt
```

In fact, as you can see, "text2" is never found on the last line, so it is not replaced by "text4", which would have happened if the "null" record delimiter had been applied only to the last of the two expressions.

How do I make it apply only to the last one?

Comment: You can't; it's a global flag (which is how command-line options _usually_ work and thus the reasonable-to-expect default), not a per-expression one.

Comment: `-0` isn't slurp mode, `-0777` is. You can also use `-g` with v5.36+. (Not the problem.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since slurping treats each file as a line, you can solve this by changing the order of the programs in the pipeline.

```bash
perl -0777pe's/text1$/text3/' file1.txt file2.txt | perl -pe's/text2$/text4/'
```

---

The above solution is very dependent on the specifics of the example you gave. The following is a general solution:

```bash
for f in file1.txt file2.txt; do
   perl -pe's/text2$/text4/' -- "$f" | perl -0777pe's/text1$/text3/'
done
```

---

With some code changes, we can come up with a better solution.

```bash
perl -0777pe's/text2$/text4/mg; s/text1$/text3/;' file1.txt file2.txt
```

---

**A note on your attempt**

Multiple `-e` options are joined with line feeds.

```
$ perl -e'print "Hello,' -e'World\n"'
Hello,
World
```

Placing options between `-e` options is therefore meaningless.